Node JS install mis-configured after reinstalling twice. (Windows 11)
I was working on a node js project.
Completely and utterly out of nowhere, node js started misbehaving somehow.
Suddenly 'node is not a recognized command'.... wtf?
I rebooted and still it was messed up.
I forgot where/how I installed node but realized i had installed through scoop, so I 'scoop uninstall node' and 'scoop install node'. It still was behaving strangely.
I just grabbed the windows installer from nodejs.org and finally it worked.
Except, until I needed to run 'npm'.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\pette\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1202:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:187:14)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v22.0.0

It's looking for npm-cli.js in the wrong directory! It's installed in C:\Program Files\npm\node_modules\bin\npm-cli.js!
How do I fix this?
I believe the cause of all this trouble may have been an accidental wipe of my $PATH env variable.
Thanks in advance.

i also ran into same problem while installing reactjs, i use vscode where i was getting same error in powershell so try switching to cmd command prompt it worked for me. hope this works

Hi ran into the same issue, where one day the error just popped out of nowhere, all I had to do was just run npm install -g npm@latest in the terminal, and it fixed it. It seems that some file was removed over the night or something. Hope it helps.

This simply results in the same error message. npm install doesn't work because npm doesn't work.

I was partially able to solve this after realizing the issue was that my entire PATH environment variable was annihilated. Several days of work was spent adding all kinds of stuff back into my path. Still wonky, but at least most of the things i need works. But I can't install node from anywhere other than from chocolatey xD
